# How to override default validation message of entity choice field?

Tags: php, symfony

I have defined foreign key in my `User` entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Region")
 */
protected $region;
```

I'd like to use it in form as a choice field.

```
$builder->add('region');
```

Which works great in fact, until I want to validate if choice is valid entity id. In fact, that works great too, but I'm getting `This value is not valid` error message and I need to override / translate it and I have no idea how. It's some kind of automatic validation. Logically, I'd say it should be overridable if I set `@Assert\Choice...`, but even when I tried it with dummy values (`message="You shall not pass", choices={1,2}`), it seemed to ignore it completely.

Answer (score 0):

Use the message parameter:

```
@Assert\Choice(message="This is not a valid region")
```

Or the multipleMessage parameter, if you allow multiple choices:

```
@Assert\Choice(multipleMessage="...")
```

See http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/constraints/Choice.html

Comment: What you did was not very explicit in the question ;)

Comment: That works only if `multiple` is set to true, which isn't in this case.

Comment: This message may not come from the ChoiceValidator then